# Find and modify an xml element by JAXB annotation on a Java field without (un)marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a Java class mapped to xml using JAXB annotations. However, the xml may contain elements not mapped to any of the class fields. For example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Book")
public class Book {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    private String bookId;

    @XmlElement(name = "Title")
    private String title;
}

<Book Id="123">
    <Title>Unknown</Title>
    <Comments>Lorem ipsum</Comments>
</Book>
```

I need to modify an element in the xml mapped to a particular field (let's say title) in my class without loosing those unmapped elements. I would like to write something like that:

```
Document xml = ...;
Field titleField = Book.class.getDeclaredField("title");
for (Node titleNode : findNodes(xml, titleField))
{
    // Remove all child nodes, insert single text node
}
```

Is there a way to find xml element(s) in the xml document that are mapped to a given Java class field without actually analyzing the annotations myself?

Comment: An alternative API to achieve this is [StAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html)

Comment: Perhaps, I did not state it clear enough: I already have a bunch of JAXB annotated classes and need to patch xml elements based on what Java fields they are mapped to.